# How to get attributes of Web Map feature which user clicked on in custom widget in ArcGIS Experience Builder application?

Tags: javascript, arcgis-online, arcgis-online-webmap, arcgis-experience-builder, jimu

I have an ArcGIS Experience Builder application, which uses a Web Map I host in ArcGIS online. This Web Map contains a feature layer with several attributes, and I can use these in Experience Builder with the stock widgets (i.e. updating dynamic text based on attributes when the user clicks on a certain feature). I am now trying to write a custom widget using Jimu which displays some text when the user clicks on a feature:

```
      jmv.view.on('click', evt => {
        const point: Point = jmv.view.toMap({
          x: evt.x,
          y: evt.y
        })

        jmv.view.hitTest(evt).then((response) => {
          console.log(response.results[0].graphic.attributes)
          // Do things with the attributes of the clicked feature
        })
      })
```

However, this code only returns the `ObjectID` attribute of the clicked feature, and none of the others. How do I access the rest of the features?

Answer (score 0):

The `outFields` property on the feature layer needs to be set to provide the desired fields before accessing the `hitTest` results.

Using a wildcard to enable all fields:

```
var layer = jmv.view.map.layers.getItemAt(0)
layer.outFields = ["*"]

// hitTest code below
```